# Simplify (A ∪ (B ∩ C)) ∪ ((B' ∩ C') ∪ C)'

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A, B, C$ be sets. Simplify $(A \cup (B \cap C)) \cup ((B' \cap C') \cup C)'$.I am generally lost on this question. Have tried using method of saying let $x$ be an element of $A$, let $y$ be an element of $B$ and let $z$ be an element of $C$ and then work from there trying to prove but it got too messy.

$x \in A$: meaning $x \not \in$  B and C

$y \in B $: meaning $y \not \in$ A and C

$z \in C $: meaning $z \not \in$ A and B

Therefore $B \cap C$ is an empty set then $x$ is an element of $A \cup (B \cap C)$

$(A \cup (B \cap C) = A$

$x \in B'$, $z \in B'$, $y \in B'$, $x \in C'$, $y \in C'$ and $z \not \in C'$

Therefore $x$ and $z$ are elements of $(B' \cap C') \cup C$

but $((B' \cap C') \cup C)'$ contains $y$ which is set $B$

so simplified we get $A \cup B$

It gives an answer but the method seems far fetched. Is there a more straightforward way to simplify?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: Have you tried making a Venn diagram?

Comment: Using the laws of de Morgan might help.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use properties of sets and go about solving it which might be considered more straightforward.

A, B and C are mutually disjoint sets.

(A ∪ (B ∩ C)) ∪ ((B' ∩ C') ∪ C)'

⟹ (A ∪ ∅) ∪ ((B' ∩ C') ∪ C)'      [∵ B and C are disjoint sets ⟺ B ∩ C = ∅]

⟹ A ∪ ((B' ∩ C') ∪ C)'          [$A ∪ ∅ = A$; Law of identity element]

⟹ A ∪ ((B ∪ C)' ∪ C)'         [$(B' ∩ C') = (B ∪ C)'$; DeMorgan's Law]

⟹ A ∪ ((B ∪ C) ∩ C')          [DeMorgan's Law]

⟹ A ∪ ((B ∩ C') ∪ (C ∩ C'))       [Distributive property]

⟹ A ∪ ((B ∩ C') ∪ ∅)         [$C ∩ C' = ∅$; Complement Law]

⟹ A ∪ (B ∩ C')            [$A ∪ ∅ = A$; Law of identity element]

⟹(A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C')         [Distributive property]

⟹(A ∪ B) ∩ C'           [∵ A and C are disjoint sets ⟹ A ⊆ C']

⟹A ∪ B           [∵ A, B and C are mutually disjoint sets ⟹ A ⊆ C' and B ⊆ C' ⟹ A ∪ B ⊆ C']

□

I hope it helps! Please let me know if I have made any mistakes